# Problems passing function using reactivevalues

Tags: r, shiny

This is an extension of the question [How to store reactive outputs values in a vector to be used in a function?](http://How%20to%20store%20reactive%20outputs%20values%20in%20a%20vector%20to%20be%20used%20in%20a%20function?)

I have implemented the same data used in the question above and added two more columns, SD_D and Ord = M_D + SD_D. Until this step the app works well but I want to add a new column which is just the previous value of Ord. To achieve this I have written a function shift(x,lag), where lag will be 1.

When the app is updated, the 4 previous values of Ord changes to NA and I need these values to calculate the lag of Rec column. How could I keep the 4 previous values of Ord?

For instance, if the user enter the values 120, 150, 110, 146 the expected result will be:

```
D        M_D     SD_D    Ord      Rec
100.00   NA      NA      100      NA
100.00   NA      NA      100      100
100.00   NA      NA      100      100
100.00   NA      NA      100      100
120.00   100.00  0.00    100.00   100
150.00   105.00  10.00   115.00   100
110.00   117.50  23.63   141.13   115
146.00   120.00  21.60   141.60   141.13
```

Here is the ui code

```
library(shiny)

fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(textInput("c1","example"),

           actionButton("update", "Update Table")
  ),

 mainPanel(tableOutput("example")

 )
)
```

and the server code

```
library(shiny)
library(zoo)

function(input, output) {

  #Example
  d <- rep(100,4)
  m <- rep(100,4)
  k <- rep(0,4)
  r <- rep(100,4)
  o <- rep(100,4)

  shift <- function(x, lag) {
   n <- length(x)
    xnew <- rep(NA, n)
    xnew[(lag+1):n] <- x[1:(n-lag)]
    return(xnew)
  }

  values <-reactiveValues(df=data.frame(D=d,M_D=m,SD_D=k,Ord=o,Rec=r))

  newEntry <- observeEvent(input$update,{
   d_new <- c(values$df$D,as.numeric(input$c1))
   r_new <- shift(values$df$Ord,1)
   m_d_new <- rollapply(d_new, mean ,  fill=NA, width=list(-1:-4))
   k_new <- rollapply(d_new, sd ,  fill=NA, width=list(-1:-4))
   o_new <- m_d_new + k_new
   values$df <- data.frame(D=d_new,M_D=m_d_new,SD_D=k_new, Ord=o_new, 
 Rec=r_new)
  })

  output$example <- renderTable({values$df})

}
```

************************* Edited *****************************************

I have found a dirty solution to include the column that I wanted. I use the same rollapply function and just change the width parameter.

My original data is

```
D        M_D     SD_D    Ord      Rec
100      100     100     100      100
100      100     100     100      100
100      100     100     100      100
100      100     100     100      100
```

and when I include the values 120, 150, 110, 146 the result is

```
D        M_D     SD_D    Ord     Rec
100.00   NA      NA      NA      NA
100.00   NA      NA      NA      NA
100.00   NA      NA      NA      NA
100.00   NA      NA      NA      NA
120.00   100.00  0.00    100.00  NA
150.00   105.00  10.00   115.00  100.00
110.00   117.50  23.63   141.13  115.00
146.00   120.00  21.60   141.60  141.13
```

I still want to use a function with lag as parameter, since I want that the user can chose this value. I have included a selectInput in my ui code and have changed my original function.

Below my ui and server code modified

```
library(shiny)
library(zoo)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(textInput("c1","Example"),

           actionButton("update", "Update Table"),

           selectInput(inputId = "L",label = "Lag value",
                       choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4), selected=1
           )
  ),#endsidebarPanel
  mainPanel(tableOutput("example")

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

 #Example
d <- rep(100,4)
m <- rep(100,4)
k <- rep(0,4)
r <- rep(100,4)
o <- rep(100,4)

## mylag function
mylag <- function(x, lag) {
         n <- length(x)
         xnew <- x[n-lag]
         return(xnew)
}


values <- reactiveValues(df = data.frame(D=d, M_D=m, SD_D=k, Ord=o, 
Rec=r)) 

 newEntry <- observeEvent(input$update,{
 d_new <- c(values$df$D,as.numeric(input$c1))
 m_d_new <- rollapply(d_new, mean ,  fill=NA, width=list(-1:-4))
 k_new <- rollapply(d_new, sd ,  fill=NA, width=list(-1:-4))
 o_new <- as.numeric(m_d_new + k_new)
 r_new <- rollapply(o_new, mean ,  fill=NA, width=list(-1:-1))     
 values$df <- data.frame(D=d_new,M_D=m_d_new,SD_D=k_new, Ord=o_new, 
 Rec=r_new)
  })

  output$example <- renderTable({values$df})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect you function `shift ` to do?

Comment: Sorry, I think that I did not explain well what I want to do with the shift function. I want just the previous value of Ord column. I have edited my question and put an example.

Comment: I don't understand when you say `the 4 previous values of Ord changes to NA` and `How could I keep the 4 previous values of Ord` because in your code you have `o_new <- m_d_new + k_new` where `o_new`  is `Ord` and  `m_d_new ` is `M_D` and `k_new` is `SD_D` and you are fine with `m_d_new` and `k_new` having `NA`. Maybe I'm not just understanding what you really are trying to do. Could you be more clearer?

Comment: As you can see in my edited post above, when I run update the original values change to NA. I would like to keep these values.